# How to split time between Berlin and Prague?

Tags: public-transport, germany, cities, central-europe, czech-republic

We're a brother (27) and sister (25).

What time division would you recommend us?

> a) Berlin -5.5 days, Prague 2.5 days
>
> b) Berlin -4.5 days, Prague 3.5 days
>
> c) Berlin -4.5 days, Dresden - 1 day, Prague 2.5 days

Comment: It might help if you specified what sort of things you're hoping to do. Museums? Galleries? Food? Beer? Parks? Tours?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is very difficult to say because it also depends on your preferences. But generally I would recommend option c) since Dresden is really worth a visit! And it is directly on the way from Berlin to Prague, so you don't have to do any detour. On the contrary you can split a long journey into two parts.

Prague is very well connected to Dresden (take the DBB bus) and from Dresden to Berlin there are a lot of fast trains.

Comment: There are direct trains between Prague and Berlin as well, with a stop in Dresden.